# Un équivalent de « You want me to do what? »

Tags: grammaire, questions

Comment traduirait-on cette phrase-là (à la quotidienne) ? J'hésite entre soit « tu me veux faire quoi ? », soit « tu veux que je fasse quoi ? ». La première me parait moins lourde, mais je ne suis pas sûr que ça suive grammaticalement les règles du français. Par exemple, est-il aussi possible de dire « je t'aide à chanter » (afin de dire « *I help you sing* ») qui emploie une structure grammaticale similaire.

Je m'intéresse aussi à la traduction du parallèle qui n'exprime pas d'étonnement : « *What do you want me to do?* » (peut-être traduite par « Qu'est-ce que tu me veux faire ? » ou « Qu'est-ce que tu veux que je fasse ? »).

Comment: Pour ta question parallèle, la deuxième proposition est la bonne, avec un bon emploi du subjonctif. Pour la première aussi, d'ailleurs mais on pourra te donner plus d'explications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ta deuxième proposition est la bonne et avec un bon emploi du subjonctif. Mais ta question reflète un souci sur l'emploi des pronoms personnels.

### 1

<strike>tu me veux faire quoi</strike>

> - Tu veux me faire quoi.

La phrase a un seul sujet : **tu**.
**Me** : pronom personnel COI (objet indirect) se place avant le verbe dont il est complément, c'est à dire *faire*.

> - Tu veux que je fasse quoi.

La phrase a deux sujets :
*Tu* est sujet de *veux*.
*Je* est sujet de *fasse*.

### 2

En français les constructions avec *vouloir* et *aider* ne sont pas similaires.

Pour *aider* voir [la banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2885).
En gros on aide quelqu'un (COD) **à** faire quelque chose.

*Vouloir* par contre n'utilise pas de préposition pour introduire le verbe qui le suit et on peut identifier deux constructions différentes :

> - Je veux partir.

Un seul sujet pour les deux actions. *Vouloir* est suivi d'un simple infinitif qui ici tient le rôle de substantif COD de *vouloir*.

> - Je veux que tu partes.

Deux sujets différents pour deux actions différentes :
- l'action de vouloir a pour sujet *je*
- l'action de partir a pour sujet *tu*
Et dans ce cas on ne fait pas suivre *vouloir* de l'infinitif mais d'une proposition complétive introduite par que avec le verbe au subjonctif.

### 3

Les remarques ci-dessus s'appliquent bien sûr de la même façon à tes deux dernières phrases :

<strike>Qu'est-ce que tu me veux faire ?</strike> 
Pour identifier un sujet différent à chaque verbe on doit dire :

> Qu'est-ce que tu veux que je fasse ?

Sinon *me* est compris comme COI (COI parce qu'en français on dit *faire **à***) et doit alors se placer avant le verbe dont il est complément (*faire*).

> Qu'est-ce que tu veux me faire ?

---

<sup>Les constructions étant si différentes en anglais et en français j'ai évité toute comparaison avec l'anglais. Mais je suppose que les anglophones pourront de toute façon faire la comparaison tous seuls.</sup>

Comment: Le calque gramatical de l'anglais est bien *« tu me veux faire quoi ». Il suffit d'expliquer que cette construction n'existe pas en français.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: c'est pas ce que veut dire ma note de fin ?

Comment: « Ta question reflète un souci sur la nature et la place des pronoms personnels. » J'ai l'impression d'entendre un professeur qui ne comprend pas le problème de son étudiant. La question de l'OP c'est bien de savoir si la même contruction gramaticale que celle qui existe en anglais existe en français. Il n'y a aucun problème concernant la place des pronoms dans cette question, ils sont placés exactement là où il faut pour pouvoir poser cette question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: il confond utilisation des pronoms  personnels et compléments dû à une mauvaise analyse de la construction en français. D'où ma réponse qui consiste à expliquer la construction en français. Tu penses qu'il faut comparer des constructions et, comme je le dis dans ma réponse je pense que dans ce cas il suffit de dire qu'elles sont différentes, (je pense que dans ce cas les comparer serait contre productif à la compréhension et qu'il est préférable d'analyser les constructions en français). Mais tu es libre de moinssoyer et de donner une autre réponse !

Comment: Le problème c'est que la première et la dernière phrase que tu proposes n'ont pas le sens que l'OP cherche, mais *what do you want to do to me*. L'explication purement grammatical peut n'être pas suffisante pour quelqu'un qui est en train d'apprendre.

Comment: @rsanchez: j'ai compris qu'il voulait dire : *tu me que je fasse quoi* / *Qu'est-ce que tu veux que je fasse ?* deux verbes deux sujets différents (*je* et *tu*) en opposition à l'autre construction qu'il propose avec un seul sujet.  Bien sûr s'il veut dire autre chose, j'ai mal compris, et il suffit que quelqu'un dise ce qu'il a compris. Ce serait quand même plus constructif pour le site de rédiger ce qu'on pense être la bonne réponse/interprétation.

Comment: @rsanchez: Par ailleurs, de par son niveau de français dans la question, et si c'est un anglophone comme il semble, l'OP a pour un anglophone un bon niveau de français et des bases grammaticales solides, en tous les cas assez pour dire tout seul s'il a compris ou pas. Écrire en anglais n'est pas un problème pour moi mais si les visiteurs viennent pour apprendre le français la traduction n'est pas le moyen le plus efficace. L'explication est un pas de plus pour aider à comprendre, donner les outils nécessaires pour aider à s'exprimer dans des situations similaires.

Comment: Dans le premier paragraphe, l'OP cherche la meilleure manière d'exprimer **un seul sens**: *You want me to do what?*. La part 1 de ton réponse lui donne deux alternatives qui expriment **deux sens différents**: *What do you want to do to me* / *You want me to do what?*, sans mentionner ce fait.

Comment: @rsanchez: où vois-tu deux alternatives ? L'OP propoe deux alternatives et je lui dis d'emblée, "la deuxième proposition est la bonne, avec un bon emploi du subjonctif."  Ensuite dans la réponse j'ai développé pourquoi le fait de mettre un ou deux sujets change la phrase.

Comment: Mais c'est dans la réponse qu'il faut répondre les questions, pas dans les commentaires. Si un commentaire est nécessaire pour que la réponse soit complète, il doit être intégré dans la réponse.

Comment: Premièrement, je te remercie, Laure. Bien que l'explication de comment les pronoms personnels fonctionnent ne m'aide pas trop (puisque, comme tu as bien remarqué, j'ai déjà une bonne base du français), je suis sûr que quelqu'un dans l'avenir puissent trouver le rigueur de ta réponse d'être très utile. Cela dit, Stéphane a bien compris pourquoi j'ai placé les pronom où je les ai placé dans ma première proposition. Je cherchais à comprendre si cette structure grammaticale de l'anglais existe en français. Évidemment, elle n'existe pas :).. P.S. Comme vous avez tous deviné, je suis anglophone :P

Comment: Si tu pourrais ajouter ta commentaire à ta réponse, comme rsanchez te suggère, je marquerai cette réponse comme la bonne !

Comment: @bronxbomber92 OK je vais l'inclure mais il ne faut jamais se presser d'accepter une réponse. On arrive parfois avec des réponses acceptées qui ne sont pas les meilleures possibles.  Tu peux aussi plussoyez ma réponse directe  ("la deuxième proposition est la bonne, avec un bon emploi du subjonctif".) et attendre une meilleure réponse. Quand je n'ai pas grand chose à dire je réponds souvent par un commentaire.

Answer (score 2):

De façon plus familière, on peut aussi dire

> Alors / au final / donc, je fais quoi ?
>
> Alors, je dois faire quoi ?

qui montre qu'il y a eu de nombreuses hésitations, que tu es confus sur ce qu'on t'a demandé et que tu veux une précision sur ce qu'on attend de toi au final.

Sinon, la forme la plus employée pour cette expression est à mon sens :

> Que veux-tu que je fasse ? / que je te fasse ? / que je fasse pour toi ?

ou si c'est pour proposer de l'aide sans sollicitation préalable :

> Que puis-je faire pour toi/t'aider ?

Comment: "Alors, je fais quoi" (et les autres) pourraient-t-elles exprimer un sens d'étonnement et non pas de confusion ?

Comment: @bronxbomber92 pas a ma connaissance. L'étonnement serait plus marqué par 'tu veux vraiment que...?'

Answer (score 0):

Ne pourrait-on pas aussi dire "Tu veux me faire faire quoi ?" (étonnement) et "Qu'est-ce que tu veux me faire faire ?" (normal).

Comment: Je trouve que le sens des phrases que tu proposes c'est un peu différent: *you want to make me do what?*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec rsanchez... en anglais votre traduction a le sens de "You want to have me do what?"

Comment: Je vous prie de m'excuser d'avoir osé intervenir, je l'ai fait car dans sa question, bronxbomber92 demandait des expressions "à la quotidienne". Par ailleurs, je ne suis pas sûre que les variantes "you want to make me do what?" ou "You want to have me do what?" soient très courantes en anglais.

Comment: +1 Je trouve aussi que "Que veux-tu me faire faire ?" rejoint souvent "Que veux-tu que je fasse ?".

Answer (score 0):

La traduction la plus correcte me semble être :

Que veux-tu que je fasse ?

Comment: C'est sans doute la formulation la plus grammaticalement correcte, mais il me semble qu'elle ne reflète pas le côté familier de la version anglaise.